# USB Drive Not Functioning

Tags: usb-drive, gparted

Using Ubuntu 13.10 on an Asus 1015E-DS03. Using GParted, I formatted my USB drive to FAT32.  Then images an ISO file to it using dd. Tried formatting again, and it just says unformatted with an error. Thanks in advanced!
[image: GParted Error]

Answer (score 0):

Hey there what did you expect when you've dd iso file to fat32 filesystem? I'm not sure about GParted error. But in any case you can just dd beginning (first 1024 bytes i guess) of your /dev/sdb

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=2
```

and unplug/plug back your drive and run GParted, try to create new partition and format it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you `dd` an ISO file to a USB drive, especially if you specify a device ( `/dev/sdb` in your case ) it overwrites the previous filesystem information and partition table in the process.

To fix this, I usually start by selecting "create partition table" from the "Device" menu:

[image]

Once you do that, you should be able to re-create your FAT 32 partition.